# Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed?

Tags: php

I am facing a problem regarding SMTP connection in php mailer, Here is my code

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function

//Load composer's autoloader
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'mine@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('mine@gmail.com', 'mine');
    $mail->addAddress('mine@gmail.com', 'mine');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('mine@gmail.com', 'mine');
    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['name'];
    $mail->Body    = $_POST['mail']."<br>" .$_POST['phn']."<br>".$_POST['des'];
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';echo "<br>";`enter code here`
    echo "<a href=index.html>Go Back";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Actually this code was running perfectly and i was getting mail but now it is not working and saying  **Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed** this as an error. Help me !!!

Thanks...

Comment: Can you confirm with your host that port 465 is open?

Comment: Try use port 587, except you have opened the port 465 and assigned it as SMTP.

Comment: how to check port 465 is open or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way... maybe the certificate is selfsigned or something like this.

> Failing that, you can allow insecure connections via the SMTPOptions
>   property introduced in PHPMailer 5.2.10 (it's possible to do this by
>   subclassing the SMTP class in earlier versions), though this is not
>   recommended as it defeats much of the point of using a secure
>   transport at all:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting